# NullPointerException on click, even with button variable set to "field variable"

Tags: java, android, variables, exception, button

I really wanted to figure it out my self to learn from it, read all the topics, and even went back to java basics to fix this, but no luck.

I have a simple app with three buttons, all I want is to set the button's background for the selected state using "setSelected(true);" in my java code. So far the button gets the background I want when selected, but I need to disable the background when another  button is pressed. I made for this an "if" statement, but as I click the other button my app crashes and I get NullPointerException.

I have set the button variable to field variable in the main activity, tried catch Block too, but it tells nothing about the bug...

What should I do in order fix this?
Regards

```
package com.example.cinemagrandmall;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private WebView myWebView;
        private View buttonRezervari;
        private View buttonHome;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);       
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){     
        @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/home.html");
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        Button home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prog_btn);
        Button rezervari = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rezervari_btn);
        Button locatie = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locatie_btn);


        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
        @Override
            public void onClick(View buttonHome) {              
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/home.html");  

              if (buttonHome.isPressed()){
                  buttonHome.setSelected(true);
                  buttonRezervari.setSelected(false);

                  // Log.i("Button", "the button works"); 
                 } 
            }       
         });

        rezervari.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View buttonRezervari) {             
            myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/rezervari.html"); 

            if (buttonRezervari.isPressed()){
                  buttonRezervari.setSelected(true);
                  buttonHome.setSelected(false);
                } 
             }
        });

         locatie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
         public void onClick(View v3) {             
         myWebView.loadUrl("http://edmondvarga.com/testing_app/locatie.html");              
            }
        });


}}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/prog_btn"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:background="@drawable/prog_btn"
         android:minHeight="40dp"  
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/locatie_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/loc_btn"
        android:minHeight="40dp" 
       />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rezervari_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/prog_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/rez_btn"
        android:minHeight="40dp"  
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
11-28 10:45:49.647: W/dalvikvm(3816): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414c4700)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.example.cinemagrandmall.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-28 10:45:49.647: E/AndroidRuntime(3816):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only created

```
`private View buttonRezervari;
 private View buttonHome;`
```

You have not initialised them. They do not refer to any widget in your layout that is why they are null. In simple words, no memory is allocated to them.

```
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

This is how you pass a reference like you have done above which you have not done for :-

```
buttonRezervari
buttonHome
```

Comment: Jeez, thanks! I spent the last few hours finding the bug, and it was right before my eyes...:D Thanks!

Comment: you can click the error in log at. It will take you directly to that line itself.

Answer (score 3):

You never update `buttonRezervari` field.

So when you try to access it on `buttonRezervari.setSelected(false);` it throws NPE.

You can update it in `onCreate` method.